# Is it legal to put <svg> resources after </body>?

Tags: html, svg

Can I put svg resources `use`d in the website behind the end of body, in order to keep
them outside of what will be rendered?

In short: Is it legal to do the following?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         viewBox="0 0 315.424 315.424" >
      <use href="#arrow" fill="rgb(0,44,89)" />
    </svg>
  </body>
  <svg>
    <g id="arrow">
      <path d="M311.929,222.266l-96.119-67.342c-1.413-0.99-2.783-1.513-4.307-1.513c-3.307,0-6.471,2.512-6.471,7.313v41.05H19.886
         c-4.962,0-8.854,4.132-8.854,9.094v35.563c0,4.962,3.892,9.343,8.854,9.343h185.146v40.81c0,4.801,3.167,7.19,6.474,7.19
         c0.001,0-0.089,0-0.089,0c1.524,0,3.032-0.461,4.445-1.451l96.09-67.306c2.214-1.55,3.473-3.864,3.473-6.375
         S314.142,223.815,311.929,222.266z" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</html>
```

Comment: Absolutely not! They don't call it the body of the document for nothing. Running it through the validator would have answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before in the comments:
It's not valid and many browser won't display your elements.
So inserting your svg assets at the top or bottom of your `<body>` is the preferrable method.

**Caution:** Hiding your asset svg via `display:none` will break some referenced definitions like:

- filters
- gradients
- masks and clip-paths

It works flawlessly for shape elements (like icons)

#### Example

```js
function displayNone() {
  document.querySelector('#svgAssets').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
  height: 10em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="displayNone()">Set display:none</button></p>
<svg viewBox="0 0 315.424 315.424">
  <use href="#arrow" fill="red" />
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <use href="#circle" fill="green" />
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <use href="#ellipse" fill="url(#gradient)" />
</svg>

<svg id="svgAssets" style="visibility:visible; width:0; height:0" aria-hidden="true">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient">
        <stop stop-color="red" offset="0%"/>
        <stop stop-color="orange" offset="100%"/>
      </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <symbol id="arrow" viewBox="0 0 315.424 315.424">
    <path d="M311.929,222.266l-96.119-67.342c-1.413-0.99-2.783-1.513-4.307-1.513c-3.307,0-6.471,2.512-6.471,7.313v41.05H19.886 c-4.962,0-8.854,4.132-8.854,9.094v35.563c0,4.962,3.892,9.343,8.854,9.343h185.146v40.81c0,4.801,3.167,7.19,6.474,7.19 c0.001,0-0.089,0-0.089,0c1.524,0,3.032-0.461,4.445-1.451l96.09-67.306c2.214-1.55,3.473-3.864,3.473-6.375 S314.142,223.815,311.929,222.266z" />
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="circle" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r=50% />
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="ellipse" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
    <ellipse cx="100" cy="50" rx="100" ry="50" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

In the above example I'm using `<symbol>` elements which could be used as an alternative to `<defs>`. They also support different `viewBox` properties for each icon.

If you just need to place icons via `<use>` you could also use external file references like so:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 315.424 315.424">
  <use href="svgIcons.svg#arrow" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

However, your svg files need to be same domain (or send with appropriate CORS headers)

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose is not to have the original `#arrow` rendered in the document, you might include it inside the `svg` in the `body`, wrapped around [`defs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs).

Demo in the snipped below.

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="0 0 315.424 315.424">
   <defs>
      <g id="arrow">
         <path d="M311.929,222.266l-96.119-67.342c-1.413-0.99-2.783-1.513-4.307-1.513c-3.307,0-6.471,2.512-6.471,7.313v41.05H19.886
            c-4.962,0-8.854,4.132-8.854,9.094v35.563c0,4.962,3.892,9.343,8.854,9.343h185.146v40.81c0,4.801,3.167,7.19,6.474,7.19
            c0.001,0-0.089,0-0.089,0c1.524,0,3.032-0.461,4.445-1.451l96.09-67.306c2.214-1.55,3.473-3.864,3.473-6.375
            S314.142,223.815,311.929,222.266z" />
      </g>
   </defs>
   <use href="#arrow" fill="rgb(0,44,89)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Kind of, I want the whole path definition at the end of my html document, rather than somewhere in the middle. I think by your solution I do not get this.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it know: `<svg style="display: none">` at the end of, yet still within the `<body>` block with your `<defs>` inside. Thank you. This video, however, discusses the issues of having a def block at the end of the document: https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/15-svg-icon-system-defs-go/

Comment: And there is ``<template>`` for inert content: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Comment: And for your use-case, you might be interested in the ``<svg-icon>`` Web Component (native JavaScript) approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64997454/how-to-eliminate-html-code-duplication-when-using-the-same-svg-icon-in-multiple/65009327#65009327