# SVG event bubbling from included images through <image> tags

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am writing a diagramming tool in HTML/CSS/Javascript and using SVG for the drawing canvas. The tool has a specific set of "building blocks" that can be placed on the canvas (i.e., not free-hand drawing of arbitrary shapes).

I have SVG icons created for my custom building blocks. Each block is a square shape. A standard decision box symbol is shown below for example:

[image: Example If block]

The circle is an input to the decision box. The green square on the right is the conditional true path and the red square in the bottom is the conditional false path.

Here is an example of a generic process block.

[image]

**Scenario:** Suppose I have placed two blocks on the canvas and want to draw a connection between the two. Connections can be drawn only between restricted junction points. For e.g., an output of a previous block can be connected to an input of a subsequent block.

As far as I understand, SVG doesn't load external javascript files when the SVG file is included using the `<svg:image href="path/to/file.svg" />` tag. So, if I want to handle a click event in a junction point (i.e, the colored circle or square representing the input/output), if I add the click event handler inside the individual svg icon file, there is duplication of code across icons.

Secondly, the canvas (i.e., `svg` element in the main HTML) is the one that is aware of the multiple blocks placed on it and can enforce the creation of valid connections. For e.g., handling the `mouseup` event and checking if a valid connection has been made and if so, rendering it on the canvas (or showing visual cues to the user such as changing the color of the connection to display valid/invalid connection).

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to organize the Javascript code for the click event handlers by avoiding duplication across the individual icon files?
2. If an individual icon handles the click events on the junction points, how does one bubble up that event back to the canvas (i.e., svg element) containing the icon embedded through an `<image>` element?

Comment: There is this "encapsulation" mechanism that isolates an SVG from its surroundings, if it is embedded as an external image. Like, in HTML, the only way to influence its elements with outside CSS, is if the `svg` element is put directly into the HTML, not if it gets embedded via `img` or `object`. [...]

Comment: [...] I am wondering if the same principle could apply here - if you embedded your blocks into the SVG using `use`, instead of `image`? `image` is still basically referring an "external" image, whereas `use` is supposed to "clone" the nodes into your SVG, as if they had been there all along. Couldn't say for sure if that will work, but I'd say it is probably worth a try.

Comment: If you're using image elements then javascript doesn't run at all in them.

Comment: Yes, `<image>` disables javascript (even if it was inlined in the svg) and `use` doesn't work either (as we would expect, but does with a caveat). I have posted an answer below of what seems to work (for me).

Comment: use a modern _native_ Web Component to create your SVGS and have full control where you add SVG, (click)handlers.. basically anything. For inspiration see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64997454/how-to-eliminate-html-code-duplication-when-using-the-same-svg-icon-in-multiple/65009327#65009327

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an approach that seems to work for my use case. I am documenting it below, just in case others have a similar issue and get to this question.

Here is a minimal self-contained HTML file to demonstrate the technique. This uses complete inlining of the SVG, CSS and Javascript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="svg-diagram-canvas" version="2.0" viewBox="0 0 300 200" width="300" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <!-- https://coolors.co/ffba49-20a39e-ef5b5b-23001e-a4a9ad -->
        <style>
            :root{
                --stroke-color1: black;
                --fill-color1: #FFBA49;
                --fill-color2: #20A39E;
                --fill-color3: #EF5B5B;
                --fill-color4: #23001E;
                --fill-color5: #A4A9AD;
                --fill-color6: teal;
                --stroke-width-normal: 2px;
            }
            .shape{ stroke:var(--stroke-color1); stroke-width:var(--stroke-width-normal); stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-linecap: round;}
            .f1{ fill:var(--fill-color1); }
            .f2{ fill:var(--fill-color2); }
            .f3{ fill:var(--fill-color3); }
            .f4{ fill:var(--fill-color4); }
            .f5{ fill:var(--fill-color5); }
            .connect-target:hover { fill:var(--fill-color2); }
        </style>
        <script type="text/ecmascript">
            function onBlockClick(evt){
                alert('Block clicked.');
            }
            function onInputClick(evt){
                alert('Input clicked.');
            }
        </script>

        <defs>
            <rect id="block" x="10" y="10" width="40" height="30" />
            <rect id="input" x="7" y="17" width="6" height="6" />
        </defs>

        <!-- using a g tag will work applying the styles and triggering the event handlers correcly !-->
        <g id="ax">
            <use href="#block" class="f1" onclick="onBlockClick(evt)"/>
            <use href="#input" class="f3 connect-target" onclick="onInputClick(evt)"/>
        </g>

        <!-- the following WON'T work for the hover CSS style or click event trigger -->
        <!--
        <use href="#ax" />
         -->

    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

The main thing to note is that the CSS styles applied on the SVG elements must be on the top level of the element usage. For e.g., in the example above the `<g id="ax">` tag greates a group of objects. The CSS styles of its descendants will get applied and the event handlers on its children and descendants get triggered correctly.

However, if we move the `<g id="ax">` into the `<defs>` section and then invoke a `<use href="#ax' />`, then neither the styles get applied (specifically the SVG element hover style called `connect-target` in the example above) nor the event handlers get triggered.

What this means is that we can create the "definitions" of the symbols under the `<defs>` section (defined in a compliant manner) and the application can clone the nodes into the HTML DOM.

If anyone has a simpler/alternative approach, I would be keen to see that.